# how to json_encode(); the Loop content so that the encoded array is ["0":content, "1":content]

Tags: jquery, ajax, loop

```
<?php
$dVC=array();
query_posts('meta_key=featuredt&posts_per_page=5');
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$dVC []= $post->post_content;?>
<div id="featuredt-<?php echo $wp_query->current_post;?>">
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featuredt', TRUE);?></div>
<?php endwhile;
endif;
json_encode($dVC);
?>
```

This is my loop at the moment.

I need the json encoded variable to look like  ["0":content, "1":content] so I can use jQuery.parseJSON() on it. I don't mind people telling me about jQuery.getJSON() but I have less of an idea how to use it then parseJSON. Please provide detailed examples when explaining, I really would appreciate any help I could get though.

Comment: let me get this right. You want to get the contents of the $dVC php variable in jquery. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Try outputting the JSON:

```
echo json_encode($dVC);
```